# Vert.x Service with threadpool executor service , CPU usage high

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, threadpoolexecutor, vert.x

i am running java application using vet.x 8 instance on 24 core CPU using centOS , used threadpool to insert in rabbitMQ , sometime my CPU usage goes to 100% and application stuck for some time
meanwhile on same server i am running rabbitMQ consumer to receive beacon  there also i am using threadpool service

```
2016-03-03 11:17:06
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.71-b01 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff088001000 nid=0x3b53 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"pool-1-thread-2" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff050104000 nid=0x3846 waiting on condition [0x00007ff110d92000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000072eca42c8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-1-thread-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff05003d800 nid=0x3845 runnable [0x00007ff110e93000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
        - locked <0x000000072ec17850> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
        - locked <0x000000072ec17830> (a java.io.DataInputStream)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:534)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"threadDeathWatcher-2-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff060265000 nid=0x3844 waiting on condition [0x00007ff111f95000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.run(ThreadDeathWatcher.java:113)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"vert.x-eventloop-thread-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff05c00f000 nid=0x3841 runnable [0x00007ff112096000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
        - locked <0x0000000411810180> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x0000000411810170> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x0000000411810128> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
 at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:618)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:306)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"vert.x-eventloop-thread-8" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff074019800 nid=0x383e runnable [0x00007ff112197000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
        - locked <0x0000000411810330> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x0000000411810320> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000004118102d8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:618)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:306)
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"vert.x-eventloop-thread-7" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff074017800 nid=0x383d runnable [0x00007ff112298000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:88)
        - locked <0x0000000411813190> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x0000000411813180> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x0000000411813138> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:618)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:306)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
"vert.x-eventloop-thread-6" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff074015000 nid=0x383c runnable [0x00007ff112399000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
        - locked <0x0000000411813340> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x0000000411813330> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x00000004118132e8> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:618)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:306)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"vert.x-eventloop-thread-7" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff074017800 nid=0x383d runnable [0x00007ff112298000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
        at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:79)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:88)
        - locked <0x0000000411813190> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
        - locked <0x0000000411813180> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
        - locked <0x0000000411813138> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:618)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:306)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


 .
    .
    similar types of threads 
    .
    .
"vert.x-worker-thread-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c6f8800 nid=0x3836 waiting on condition [0x00007ff11299f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000041181b260> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c0bd800 nid=0x3832 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c0bb800 nid=0x3831 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c0b8800 nid=0x3830 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c0b6000 nid=0x382f runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

    "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c08b000 nid=0x382d in Object.wait() [0x00007ff113ffe000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
            at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
            - waiting on <0x0000000411821098> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
            at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
            at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
            - locked <0x0000000411821098> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

    "main" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c009000 nid=0x3819 waiting on condition [0x00007ff153b03000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
            at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            - parking to wait for  <0x0000000411825030> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
            at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:834)
      at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:236)
            at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter.block(Starter.java:382)
            at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter.runVerticle(Starter.java:376)
            at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter.<init>(Starter.java:88)
            at org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter.main(Starter.java:55)

    "VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c087000 nid=0x382c runnable

    "GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c01e800 nid=0x381a runnable

    "GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c020800 nid=0x381b runnable

    "GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c022800 nid=0x381c runnable

    "GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c024800 nid=0x381d runnable

    "GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007ff14c026000 nid=0x381e runnab
```

Comment: For I/O operation, you can try to use it in a worker verticle or vertex.executeBlocking in a normal verticle. You can find more details in vertx core document: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are calling your rabbitmq client from the event loop. It is usually forbidden because you are blocking the event loop. You should use your rabbitmq client from vertx.executeBlocking to deal with a remote service like rabbitmq. You code will be executed with a thread from the worker pool. From vert.x 3.3 you can monitor more closely the worker pool.

I would recommend to try the rabbitmq-client for Vert.x: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rabbitmq-client/java/ as it manages the executeBlocking stuff for you.